# How to get each item from a listbox and store it to multiple textboxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox

[If you click this link to see this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Pf9.png) I have a listbox containing various numerical items. I like to know how I can get each item from the list and store it to the textboxes.

Since each textbox is named TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, etc, I tried using this code,

```
        For i = 1 To 15

            Me.Controls(String.Format("TextBox{0}", i)).Text = item.Value

        Next
```

But it only gets the final item from the textbox and puts them all in the first 15 Textboxes. [Click to view the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC86t.png)

What I would like is a loop code that will get the first item from the listbox and store it in textbox1, get the second item from the listbox and store it in textbox2, and so on.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you assign the same thing, i.e. `item.Value`, every iteration of the loop, why would you be surprised that you get the same value every time? If you expect to use a different value every iteration then you need to get a different value every iteration. The question you actually want an answer to is how to get items from a `ListBox` in a loop and that is a question that you can easily answer for yourself.

Comment: The other question could be *how those values ended up in a ListBox when their place is apparently somewhere else*. A ListBox shouldn't be used as a *repository* for data loaded from some source. Use a `List(Of Decimal)` or a `List(Of class)` to store your values and distribute them where they belong using a more appropriate *selector*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per jmc's suggestion you should also pull a different item from the list:

```
    For i = 1 To 15

        Me.Controls(String.Format("TextBox{0}", i)).Text = LISTBOXNAME.Items(i - 1).Value
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Next
```

Remember that arrays are indexed from 0

-- none of this is a great way to do these things, incidentally. Your textboxes should be well named, you should parse your text into proper class objects with named properties etc.. but if all youre after is a quick hack now that will be hard to maintain in the future (as having a single form with X textboxes on named textbox1, 2, ... 37 wwould be) then it'll suffice